# iOS UIImagePNGRepresentation crash due to "Memory Pressure"

Tags: ios

I have UIImagePicker and UICollectionView  in my view controller. I'am taking pictures and on 4th picture (it is also new line in collection view) application crashes due to "Memory Pressure". UIImagePicker delegate:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // Do picture get here
    NSError *error;
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSNumber *imageNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[databaseManagementService selectTaskPictures].count];
    NSString *imageName = [[imageNameDefault stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:objectFormat, imageNumber]] stringByAppendingString:extensionPNG];

    // Do picture save to documents directory here
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];

    // Do UIImagePicker dismiss here
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    // Do picture details save to database here
    TaskManagerTaskPicture *taskPicture = [[TaskManagerTaskPicture alloc] init];

    taskPicture.filename = imageName;
    taskPicture.id = imageNumber;
    taskPicture.title = imageName;

    taskPicture.pictureID = self.taskObject.id;
    taskPicture.taskID = self.taskObject.id;
    taskPicture.locationID = self.taskObject.location.id;

    [databaseManagementService insertTaskPictureObject:taskPicture andError:&error];

    // Do task picture update here
    // Do task object SELECT here
    self.taskObject = [databaseManagementService selectTaskWithID:self.taskObject.id];

    // Do task picture objects retreive from task object here
    self.taskPictureObjects = [self.taskObject.taskPicture allObjects];

    // Do collection data reload here
    [self.taskPicturesCollectionView reloadData];
}
```

Until now I have been debuting and realized that trouble is dousing by line:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: check the size of your image that you are picking ..

Comment: 3264 × 2448. Does size matter?

Comment: Obviously size matters thats the reason of your crash. Resize your image or set your picker quality to low quality to avoid crash.

Comment: So, what is the reason? It is not enough memory in sandbox?

Comment: Its not the sandbox memory issue , its the ram memory that iOS gives to app which is limited so you should optimize your app as much as possible.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the easiest way to reduce quality?

Comment: imgPicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame1280x720;   Use videoQuality to reduce size of your image

Comment: Changed quality... Application still crashing... A lots memory warnings and Terminated due to Memory Pressure

Comment: And actually this does not change image resolution...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60603/discussion-between-leena-and-jacob-jones).

Comment: I still have no answer. I have updated my question with more details...

Comment: Solution to decrease picture size isn't quite a good deal. It just take more time for application to crash. For example, Im able to take about 150 pictures of size 568x320 to crash...

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain better the flow of your app?

However try implementing this code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // Do picture get here

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        NSError *error;
        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

        NSNumber *imageNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[databaseManagementService selectTaskPictures].count];
        NSString *imageName = [[imageNameDefault stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:objectFormat, imageNumber]] stringByAppendingString:extensionPNG];

        // Do picture save to documents directory here
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
        [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Do UIImagePicker dismiss here
            [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

            // Do picture details save to database here
            TaskManagerTaskPicture *taskPicture = [[TaskManagerTaskPicture alloc] init];

            taskPicture.filename = imageName;
            taskPicture.id = imageNumber;
            taskPicture.title = imageName;

            taskPicture.pictureID = self.taskObject.id;
            taskPicture.taskID = self.taskObject.id;
            taskPicture.locationID = self.taskObject.location.id;

            [databaseManagementService insertTaskPictureObject:taskPicture andError:&error];

            // Do task picture update here
            // Do task object SELECT here
            self.taskObject = [databaseManagementService selectTaskWithID:self.taskObject.id];

            // Do task picture objects retreive from task object here
            self.taskPictureObjects = [self.taskObject.taskPicture allObjects];

            // Do collection data reload here
            [self.taskPicturesCollectionView reloadData];
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: Hi! Sorry, but your solution doesn't work. This app just capturing pictures and saves it to documents directory as well as saves picture kind of metadata to database.